# Find the aree of the region bounded by the curve $k$ and the tangents drawn from the point $T$ (using integration!)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The curve $k$ is given with $$x^2+y^2-12x-4y+24=0$$ ie $(x-6)^2+(y-2)^2=16$, and the point is $T(2,6)$.

I have already found the points at which the cirle and tangents intersect: ($D_1(2,2), D_2(6,6)$). The tangents are perpendicular to each other so the area of the shape could be found by subtracting the area of the circle segment $⌓D_1D_2$ from the area of the triangle $\Delta TD_1D_2$.

Now, the formula for the area bounded by two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on a segment $[a,b]$ is $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx$, so here that would mean $a=2, b=6, f(x)=\sqrt{16-(x-6)^2}+2, g(x)=x$ but I'm not sure if this is the correct way? I'm not really good at integration and I'm not really looking forward to solving this integral, so are there maybe some other easier solutions to this problem? (but it still has to be by using integrals!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did correctly. 
Refer to the graph:

[image]

Next set up the integral:
$$\int_2^6 \left(6-\left(\sqrt{16-(x-6)^2)}+2\right)\right) dx=4\int_2^6 \left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x-6}{4}\right)^2}\right)dx.$$
Denote: $\frac{x-6}{4}=\sin t \Rightarrow dx=4\cos t \ dt$. Then:
$$I=4\int_{-\pi/2}^0 (1-\cos t)\cdot 4\cos t \ dt=16\int_{-\pi/2}^0 \left(\cos t-\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\right)dt=\\$$
$$16\left(\sin t-\frac t2-\frac{\sin 2t}{4}\right)\big{|}_{-\pi/2}^0 =16-4\pi.$$

Alternatively, the green area is the area of the square minus the area of the quarter circle:
$$I=4^2-\frac{\pi\cdot 4^2}{4}=16-4\pi.$$